# why does a parent element moves as i give margin to child element like a <p> tag nested inside a <div>?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I am giving `top-margin:40px` to a `<div>` element which has `<p>` nested in it.
But its taking  some extra margin an extra space and the body margin is set is zero. See I couldn't where is this coming from.

I am guessing that `<p>` element has its default top and bottom margins when I set  them to zero no extra comes up on the top margin of div.

So the div is moving because of margin of `<p>` is there's any way I stop movement of `<div>` while applying margin to `<p>` element.

See here's my code

```
  <style>
body{
margin:0px;
}
p{
color:white;
font-size:76px;
text-align:center;



letter-spacing:14px;
font-weight:600;
text-shadow:15px 5px 15px white;

}
.con3{
height:400px;
background-color:black;

margin-top:50px;


}
</style>


<body>

<div class="con3"> <p>HELLO </p></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What exactly is happening?  It looks to me like your div with class .con3 should be 50px from the top.

Comment: @jae.phoenix no there is an extra space coming along with the top margin:50px